# DocView: Nuisance popup of page number in viewing .dvi files

Tags: microsoft-windows, docview, popup

I use DocView under Emacs 26.1 under Cygwin 10.0.2 under Windows 10.0.  I use it chiefly for reading .dvi files. I discovered it by accident and find it extremely useful, but I cannot find any documentation for it.

A continual minor irritation is that a little popup appears repeatedly at seemingly random times & places on the screen, telling the current page number in the document, and often obscuring what I am trying to read.  I have learned to flick it away with the trackball, but it is distracting, and I wish I could get rid of it.

(I tried to sign up using Google, but could not find my way thru the procedure.)